# First Order Theories

Tags: logic

Are there first order theories where every sentence or its negation is a theorem of the theory?  I know there are many examples of theories without this property, such as fields and statements such as (4+1)=0.  In the rational numbers this is false while in a 5 element finite field it is true.  I am curious as to whether there exist any other theories where all logical sentences or their negations are theorems.

Comment: Many, among them the theory of algebraically closed fields of any given characteristic, and the theory of real-closed fields.

Answer (score 3):

Yes; this is exactly the definition of a [complete theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_theory).